# How to define scala compiler plugins in Bazel?

Tags: scala, sbt, bazel, kind-projector

Currently I use rules_scala in conjunction with sbt-bazel to try an convert from sbt to bazel.

I'm currently hitting an issue with the 'kind-projector' plugin not being used during the build.

ie. compilerPlugin("org.spire-math" % "kind-projector" % "0.9.8")

Does anyone have experience working with scalac plugins in Bazel?